# Using both MyIsam & Innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

For past few days I was in a great confusion deciding whether to use MyIsam or Innodb, with both having their own pros and cons. My table will have large amount of data with heavy INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT operations.

I decided to create two tables of same structure; `tbl_mytbl_innodb(innodb engine)` and `tbl_mytbl_myisam(myisam engine)` I then created two triggers on `tbl_mytbl_innodb` for INSERT and UPDATE events that will insert/update `tbl_mytbl_myisam`. So it will always write to `tbl_mytbl_innodb` and read from `tbl_mytbl_myisam`.

Is this process correct, or do I need to do it a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that's the opposite of a correct process.  My personal recommendation is use InnoDB for almost all business activities, as it supports transactions...  the only use I've found for MyISAM is full text searches (dunno why that's not available in InnoDB) but I freely admit that's a personal preference.

Using triggers to synchronize the same data across multiple tables can't be good.  Define your business requirements and choose an engine.  If you need to use the other engine for a specific requirement, define that and populate a subset of data as necessary.

Comment: Full text search coming to an InnoDB near you! http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-full-text-search-tutorial/

Comment: @Michael: Woah! Did it just get a little bit chilly downstairs, and did the FAA start granting pilot licenses to swine?

Comment: so I think I shud stick to innodb. But I've read that searching is fast in myisam. How much is that true?

Comment: @MarcB haha! Took me a few seconds to figure those out. Anyway, definitely lots of exciting stuff coming up for MySQL.

Comment: @user942201: Yes MyISAM is fast; InnoDB is pretty darn fast too, though.  Unless you're chunking millions of records, though, I doubt you'd notice the difference.

Answer (score 4):

That's a silly way to go. The only time you should use both in parallel is if you require transactions+foreign keys **AND** fulltext indexes. You'd use triggers to sync up the fulltextable fields in a MyISAM table, and otherwise keep everything in InnoDB.

There's few usage cases where MyISAM is preferable over InnoDB, and the major one is the lack of fulltext support in InnoDB.

Comment: Hah my answer was almost exactly the same thing.